# Updating FileField in Django Form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Playing around with `FileFiled` and trying to update a form. I think my problem comes from the views.py.

I have a template where I can see a product, and I have the option to update the product by clicking on the update button.

When clicking on the update button, I am redirected to a form where I can update the product.

**template**

```
    {% for TermsAndConditions in commercial_list %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'update-commercial' TermsAndConditions.id %}">Update
            </a>    
    {% endfor %}
```

**templateform.py**

```
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <h6>Upload terms</h6>
        {{ form.attachment| as_crispy_field}}

            {% if url %}
            <p>Uploaded file <a href="{{url}}">{{url}}</a></p>

            {%endif%}

        <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="profile-btn" class="btn btn-primary custom-btn">Update</button>
        </form>
```

My normal upload form (without `FileField`) looks like this:

**views (without `FileField`)**

```
def update_commercial(request, termsandconditions_id):
    commercials = TermsAndConditions.objects.get(pk=termsandconditions_id)
    form = TermsAndConditionsForm(request.POST or None, instance=commercials )
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('list-commercial')
    return render(request, 'main/update_commercial.html',{'form':form,'commercials':commercials})
```

With the addition of the `FileField`, I thought I would do something like this:

**views (with `FileField`)**

```
def update_commercial(request, termsandconditions_id):
    commercials = TermsAndConditions.objects.get(pk=termsandconditions_id)
    form = TermsAndConditionsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES ,instance=commercials ) #the change being request.FILES
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('list-commercial')
    return render(request, 'main/update_commercial.html',{'form':form,'commercials':commercials})
```

Problem is, when I do that the update button in the template becomes invalid (it doesn't redirect to the update form).

I think my problem is how to handle the `or None` and `request.FILES` together. I tried different combinations but none have worked. Hoping someone might be able to shed some light.

(I have add the models and url files, as I dont think these are the problem and didnt want to make this post longer than it should be, but feel free to let me know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out in the end.

Posting the answer just in case for anyone who needs it.

I needed to repeat `or None` for request.FILES.

```
def update_commercial(request, termsandconditions_id):
    commercials = TermsAndConditions.objects.get(pk=termsandconditions_id)
    form = TermsAndConditionsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,instance=commercials )
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('list-commercial')
    return render(request, 'main/update_commercial.html',{'form':form,'commercials':commercials})
```